# Рабочий пример отображения Youtube ролика в FancyBox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, javascript, youtube

Кто может поделиться?

Вот такой код у меня отображает видео не по центру экрана, и iframe видео без размеров:

```
getVideo(id, function (response) {
    $.fancybox({
        // hide the related video suggestions and autoplay the video
        //'href' : this.href.replace(new RegExp('watch\\?v=', 'i'), 'embed/') + '?rel=0&autoplay=1',
        'width' : 640,
        'height' : 480,

        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                locked: false
            },
            title: {
                type: 'inside' // to append the html
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для корректной работы видео нужно добавить `helper - media`, у меня это подключено вот так:

```
$('.link').fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        helpers : {
            media : {}
        }
    });
```

А в html вот такой код:

```
<a class="link" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=код видео" data-rel="media">
    Смотреть видео
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://fancybox.net/blog  Пункт с цифрой 4 (пункты там перечислены в обратном порядке) Show youtube clips. Try now.